# PHP - Table id the same

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, html-table, rows

How can I put identical columns (sorted by "level" in this case) together? I am making a highscore where I list them by level from my database. I want them to have the same ID if they are the same level.

But I do not want to display the ID on the others. Only the first one.
Here is an example:

```
ID - Name - Level
1 - John - 5
2 - David - 4
3 - Josh - 3
   - Sam - 3
4 - George - 2
```

So I want to put them together, but if they have the same level, only the first one displays the ID.

I don't want it to look like:

```
1 - John - 5
2 - David - 4
3 - Josh - 3
3 - Sam - 3
4 - George - 2
```

Right now, it is just listing everyone, and giving each one a unique ID. Even if they have the same "level".
How can I fix this? Here is my code:

```
<?php
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rookstayers ORDER BY level DESC LIMIT 0, 500");
            $id = 1;
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                $name = $row['name'];
                $level = $row['level'];
                $world = $row['world'];
                $account = $row['accountstatus'];
                $status = $row['onlinestatus'];
                $onrow = '';
                $typeServ = '';

                $player_name = urlencode($name);

                if ($status == 1){
                    $status = 'Online';
                    $onrow = 'online';
                } else {
                    $status = 'Offline';
                    $onrow = 'offline';
                }

                if ($account == 'Premium Account'){
                    $account = 'Premium';
                } else {
                    $account = 'Free';
                }

                if ($world == 'Aurora' || $world == 'Aurera'){
                    $typeServ = 'active';
                } else {
                    $typeServ = '';
                }

            echo "<tr class=" . $typeServ . ">";
             echo "<td>" . $id . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $name . " <a href='http://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=characters&name=" . $player_name . "' target='_blank'><img src='../../img/websites/tibia.png' title='Tibia Profile'></a><a href='http://www.pskonejott.com/otc_display.php?character=" . $player_name . "' target='_blank'><img src='../../img/websites/pskonejott.png' title='Pskonejott'></a>" . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $level . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $world . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $account . "</td>";
              echo "<td class=" . $onrow . ">" . $status . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

            $id++;
}
          echo "</tbody>";
        echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Although you can do this in the database, this type of presentation logic is best done in php, by comparing the current to previous value in the loop that prints the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a temporary variable for the current level and check it to see if the id will be shown on the output or not.

```
    $id = 1;
     $last_player_lvl = '';
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
      ///....

     echo "<tr class=" . $typeServ . ">";
                         echo "<td>" . ( ($last_player_lvl == $row['level']) ? '' : $id ) . "</td>";
                          echo "<td>" . $name . " <a href='http://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=characters&name=" . $player_name . "' target='_blank'><img src='../../img/websites/tibia.png' title='Tibia Profile'></a><a href='http://www.pskonejott.com/otc_display.php?character=" . $player_name . "' target='_blank'><img src='../../img/websites/pskonejott.png' title='Pskonejott'></a>" . "</td>";
                          echo "<td>" . $level . "</td>";
                          echo "<td>" . $world . "</td>";
                          echo "<td>" . $account . "</td>";
                          echo "<td class=" . $onrow . ">" . $status . "</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
if($last_player_lvl == $row['level']){
    $id = $id;
}else{
    $id++;
}
$last_player_lvl = $row['level'];  
//....
```

Comment: tried your code but it's syntax errors on multiple lines. did you forget to include something in the code? i copy/pasted the lines u added. Could u maybe add the full code I also had? I might have put it on wrong place, idk. Im new to php so i dont know everything like that yet

Comment: oh i noticed, u put $d instead of $id. but now i fixed that, and it is 0 errors. but every ID is blank now. i also assume u made "if" statements?

Comment: sorry for that, I was simulating your data through array. Let me update the code.

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$id' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\index\top\index.php on line 177` which is this line `$id = ($last_player_lvl == $row['level']) ? $id : $id+1;`

Comment: please check again, i've changed that ternary operation to if-else

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\xampp\htdocs\index\top\index.php on line 176` on this: `if($last_player_lvl == $row['level']){`

Comment: sorry, I'm at work and pastebin is blocked here. I noticed there was a stray code there that has no simi-colon just before the if-else. I've removed it. Please check the updated code

Comment: That worked! :) But I wonder, is my LIMIT 500 still going to work? I want the top 500 IDs, sorted by level. Would this make the list shorter because of the duplicate IDs? I basically want 500 rows displayed in my table on the website

Comment: Great! The LIMIT 500 will still apply from the database end. It will fetch the top 500 rows on your table and the list on your page will still show 500 although the id may not reach 500 if there are multiple players with the same level.